# Javascript object desctructuring

Tags: javascript

I'm completely new to Javascript and building a booking calendar for car rental page and not sure how to get specific values out of object. I googled Javascript Object desctructuring, but only found out how to console.log all of the keys.

I have following code which outputs objects values (pic related)

```
$(this).datepicker('setUTCDates', newDates);
console.log(newDates)
```

[image]

, but I'm trying to get only the date, which I thought would be done with

```
$(this).datepicker('setUTCDates', newDates);
console.log(newDates.getDay())
```

However, I'm getting getDay() function doesn't exist.

I also tried putting this into Map:

```
$(this).datepicker('setUTCDates', newDates);
const obj = newDates;
const map = new Map(Object.entries(obj));
console.log(map);
```

, but getting following output:

[image]

Now I'm not sure how to scrape out only value from given key. I'm also not sure what I'm looking at when I open the console and skimming through object, if anyone can point me out to read upon that I'd be thankful.

Comment: can you please post your first code output, hope that will make sense to me

Comment: It's the whole object and its values - [Mon Nov 01 2021 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)] as posted in picture.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show the actual data, rather than a screenshot. You can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(newDates, null, 2))` to get a nicely formatted output.

Comment: Did you try newDates[0].getDay() ?

Comment: Note that you likely have an array, not an object, in `newDates`. `getDay()` will return the day of the week as a number, with Sunday as 0 and Saturday as 6.

Comment: @Thallius, now I'm getting the right value, whichever day I'm clicking. However, when I for example click Day 1 and then Day 2, I'm only getting value 1 only, instead of 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(this).datepicker('setUTCDates', newDates);
newDates.map(date => console.log(date.getDay());
```

`newDates` is an array. so, first, you have to loop through the array and console each item or item property or method. that will work for sure.

Comment: Thanks, solved. Works for multiple options also.

Comment: Using array.map without need of the result array is a code smell. Use each instead

Comment: @Thallius thanks for your suggestion, I just intend to help with his previous context. that's why show by using `map` instead of `forEach`.